# Getting data from tableviewcell to 2nd view

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, persistence

I am very new to this and am trying to learn by creating a few little apps for myself. 
I have a navigation-based app where the user taps the row to select a film title - I then want the second view to show details of the film.

Thanks to a very helpful person here I am getting the results of the row pressed as 'rowTitle' as follows :

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];
NSString *rowTitle = [nameSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"rowTitle = %@", rowTitle);
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

I am, however, struggling to make the data at 'rowTitle' available to the 2nd view -

Basically, if I can get the info - for example rowTitle is "aliens2" - I want to be able to add a new extension to the end of the string returned by 'rowTitle' in order to point to an image (if that makes sense) in the second view...

Something like

`tempImageName=[** this is where the info from rowTitle needs to be I suppose**];
 tempImageType=@".png";
 finalImageName=[tempImageName stringByAppendingString:tempImageType];`

Does this make sense to anyone (apologies if it doesnt - I know what I want but how to explain it is a little more awkward!)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `stringByAppendingPathExtension` to add the png extension, if you really need to do that.  But that depends on what you are going to do with it; you may not need the full file name just to just a file, for instance - pathForResource:ofType: can take the extension as the type argument (but imageNamed: likes the full filename).

You should add a property in your second view controller for the image name, then create and push/present the view controller in your select method.

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
vc.imageName = tempImageName;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```